# How can I back up a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Last time when I was working with my SQL Server 2014 and suddenly due to a power failure my database goes corrupted and next time after running DBCC CHECKDB I found some of stored procedures that I have created on my SQL Server are still missing. So there is any method from which I can create a successful backup for my stored procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One Possibilty is:
In SQL Server Manangement Studio **rightlick on your Database - Tasks - Generate Scripts...**
Here you can specify which object you want to script and where to save the script file.

What's my favourite solution (though it's more work) is to have all my databases in **Database Projects** in Visual Studio. (Keyword: SQL Server Data Tools). Don't know if that is interesting for you but it's very powerful and a great thing to deploy databases, manage source code (TFS for example)...all the visual studio benefits.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution here is to backup the entire database, as you stored procedure will have dependencies - like tables, columns, views, etc. that are in the database. 
If you just want to retrieve the text of the stored procedure and save it to a file, you can use `sp_helptext`. For example:

```
sp_helptext sp_procedureName
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a clear text versioned repository of all your procedures at all times.
Make one file per procedure !!!

**Good practice when working with DB scripts**

> 1) Keep a versioned repository of all your stored procedures.
>
> 2) Commit often !
>
> 3) Create a tag after each deployment.
>
> 4) Never update procedures directly on DB.
>
> 5) Keep a testing environment in sync with your production.
>
> 6) Create a management procedure to often recreate and test your procedures on the testing environment.

**Concatenate SQL files from your repository into one file ready for easy deployment**

Create a bat (if on Windows) file to merge *.sql files into one text file for deployment. Make *.txt files for the procedure files that you don't want to be included in deployments. Keep in mind that this merging script will print ECHO on each line that has nothing else than empty characters. Empty lines are accepted. Here an example:

```
@ECHO ON
REM Prepare variables
REM CD "C:\PRO\integ_bh\trunk"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET now=!date:~10,4!_!date:~7,2!_!date:~4,2!
SET staging_file=One_File.txt
SET staging_file_with_date=One_File_%now%.txt
SET file_content=

REM Remove files if already exists
REM IF EXIST %staging_file_with_date% DEL %staging_file_with_date%
REM COPY NUL %staging_file_with_date%    
IF EXIST %staging_file% DEL %staging_file%
COPY NUL %staging_file%

REM concatenate files    
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b *.sql') do ( for /f "delims=" %%c in (%%f) do ( set file_content=%%c ) & ECHO !file_content!>>%staging_file% )
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b *.sql') do ( for /f "delims=" %%c in (%%f) do ( set file_content=%%c ) & ECHO !file_content!>>%staging_file_with_date% )
```

**Copy the creation statements of all stored procedures in one file**

To make one file of your procedures from database:
Easy to print them in clear text from time to time. Separated by GO. Now you can save them in one file and keep a version before any DB updates.

```
CREATE 
    TABLE 
    #integ_bh_procedures (
        [Text] VARCHAR(MAX)
    );
DECLARE
    @SQL_text VARCHAR(MAX),
    @SchemaName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @RoutineName VARCHAR(MAX);
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE procedures_cursor CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT  s.name [SchemaName] ,o.name [RoutineName]
FROM sys.sql_modules p
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON p.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE UPPER(p.[definition]) LIKE UPPER('%dbo%'); -- Use your schema here

OPEN procedures_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM procedures_cursor
    INTO @SchemaName, @RoutineName;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    PRINT('-- sp_helptext ''[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @RoutineName + ']''');

    DELETE FROM #integ_bh_procedures;
    INSERT INTO #integ_bh_procedures
    EXEC('sp_helptext ''[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @RoutineName + ']''');
    INSERT INTO #integ_bh_procedures ([Text]) VALUES(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'GO'),(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '-- ################################################################################################ --'),(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + ''),(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + ''),(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '');
    FETCH NEXT FROM procedures_cursor
    INTO @SchemaName, @RoutineName;

    SET @SQL_text = ( SELECT '' + [Text]
        FROM #integ_bh_procedures
        FOR XML PATH(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)');
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    PRINT @SQL_text;

END
CLOSE procedures_cursor;
DEALLOCATE procedures_cursor;
DROP TABLE #integ_bh_procedures;
```

There are other simple solutions to work with stored procedures. Depending on your permissions over the database, you might have difficulties using the default instruments that SQL Management Studio provides. Not sure if your lost procedures can be recovered. I just show you how I never loose my work.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are the same as code, so if this is a production issue, I would expect the code to be source controlled.  If you have that, then you simply get the code from the source control.  If this is a personal database, you can occasionally script out your objects and save to a file, or create nightly database backups that you can restore later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

exec sp_rename 'old Name of sproc' , 'new name of sproc'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).